# Bluemix and peaks of traffic - how to protect from crashing

Tags: security, ibm-cloud

I want to protect my node app from high http traffic peaks so app does not crash (could be an attack or just unexpected peak).

Load balancers are usually the way to go to protect the app. You can define rules like routing the traffic somewhere else if traffic is above a threshold for example.

Do you have a recommended way to implement similar feature with a node application running on Bluemix CF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the ["Auto-scaling" service](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/Auto-Scaling/index.html) in IBM Bluemix to define policies that will automatically add more instances of your application when the existing CPU or memory usage reaches a threshold.

Bluemix will load-balance the traffic between all instances of your application that are running.

This [example application](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-bluemix-autoscale/) shows you the "Auto-scaling" service in action.

Comment: Aw I see. That's not currently supported in IBM Bluemix at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Bluemix offers *Monitoring and Analytics* service that you can use to help you to gain the visibility and control that you need over your application.

https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#services/monana/index.html#gettingstartedtemplate

It provides instant visibility and transparency into your applications performance and health. This will help you identify the load, but it does not provide a mechanism to throttle the load.